# Is it possible to pass event from event handler to another function + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done the event delegation in row using jQuery as below:

```
// row is dynamically created, MarketingTaskTracker is js constructor function inside which i've defined my functions (eg editMTTDetails, prepareDataForMTTDetails)

    $(row).on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", {eventID: eventID, marketingTaskCode: marketingTaskCode}, MarketingTaskTracker.editMTTDetails);

    this.editMTTDetails = function(event) {
       // I can access information related to event here i.e alert(event.data.eventID)
       // I want to pass the event in function below and be able to access information related to event
       //this.prepareDataForMTTDetails(event);
    };

    this.prepareDataForMTTDetails = function(event) {
        // Need to be able to access event related data in this function as below 
        alert(event.data.eventID);
        alert(event.data.marketingTaskCode);
        alert($(event.target).attr("id"));
    };
```

I just want to be able to pass the event from event handler function to another function and access event related information in the second function.

Comment: `event` is just like any other variable, you can pass it around just like others

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: You wouldn't use `this` in the editMTTDetails though as it will be the element processing the event.  You will want to use `MarketingTaskTracker.prepareDataForMTTDetails` most likely

Comment: Thanks Taplar for the suggesstion and it did work. I'm aware of using className.functionName() vs this.functionName(). I'm not sure why my 'this' lost the scope without any postback.

Comment: Because when you are inside a function that is executed as an event handler, the `this` is changed, in the context of the function, to be the element that the event is being processed on.  It is expected behavior.  @RameshPun

Comment: Thanks for the response@Patrick. @Taplar Thanks for pointing my mistake. Learned more about events and event handler.